# AWK validate Field with Regex

Tags: regex, awk, expression

I'm trying to define a proper regular expression that will validate a field.

The field is 26 chars long and can have: any letter (lower or uppercase), whitespaces ( ), commas (,), hyphens (-) or forward slashes (/).

The program should:

Identify whether or not there's an improper char in field $3 via if ( $3 !~ /regex/ ).
If that is the case, show the improper chars (in this case: $ and *) via the showChars() function.

Current code:

```
awk '
   function showChars(fieldIn) {
      split(fieldIn,chars,"")
      for ( i=1; i<=length(chars); i++ ) {
         if (chars[i] !~ regex) {
            print "Invalid char found:" chars[i]
         }
      }
   }

   BEGIN {
      FS=""
      FIELDWIDTHS="4 4 26"
      regex="[a-zA-Z/, \t-]$"
   }

   {
      if ( $3 !~ /regex/ ) {
         print "Line " NR ": Problem in field"
         print "$3:"$3
         showChars($3)
         next
      } else {
         print "Line " NR ": OK"
         next
      }
   }
' $filename
```

This particular code, enters the if in every case but showChars() doesn't always show invalid chars, makes me wonder why it entered the if in the first place.

Example of input filename:
Invalid field:
!!!!----JOHN,DOE/-SMITH     $*    (end of line after 4+4+26 char fields)
Valid field:
!!!!----ANA,DE/LACROIX            (end of line after 4+4+26 char fields)

filename:

```
!!!!----JOHN,DOE/-SMITH $*        
!!!!----ANA,DE/LACROIX
```

Comment: `$3 !~ /regex/` should be `$3 !~ regex` but you need to provide a sample input with expected output to be able to get further regex help.

Comment: `i < lenght(chars)` ? You probably meant `i < length(chars)`, ? Good luck.

Comment: an example could be: John,Doe/Smith  (filled with whitespaces to occupy 26 chars in total) and inserting any other char such as & within the 26 chars, should show & as the output of showChar().

Comment: Try `regex="^[a-zA-Z/, \t-]{26}$`

Comment: Not regex="^[a-zA-Z/, \t-]{26}$" nor regex="[a-zA-Z/, \t-]{26}$" worked. But regex="[a-zA-Z/, \t-]$" did the trick!, thank you.

Comment: You're escaping chars that don't need to be and/or shouldn't be escaped and not using a character class when you probably should in your regexp `"([a-zA-Z]*)|([\-|\s|\/|\,]*)"`. [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can help you.

Comment: Regarding [Not `regex="^[a-zA-Z/, \t-]{26}$"` nor `regex="[a-zA-Z/, \t-]{26}$"` worked. But `regex="[a-zA-Z/, \t-]$"` did the trick!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77875540/awk-validate-field-with-regex#comment137289984_77875540) - the first 2 are trying to match 26 characters, the first a full-string match, the second partial, while the last one is matching 1 character at the end of a string so you shouldn't be surprised that they behave differently, the question is what are you trying to do - match 26 chars or 1?

Comment: Thanks I edited my original post because it is entering the if in cases where the showChars() function is not listing any invalid chars, I still don't know why.

Comment: Thanks, I edited the post to update the changes I've made so far.
$filename is a separate unix file, described as a code block near the end of the post so it can be reproducted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be what you're trying to do, using GNU for various extensions:

```
awk '
   function showchar(fieldIn,   chars,numChars,i) {
      numChars = split(fieldIn,chars,"")
      for ( i=1; i <= numChars; i++ ) {
         if ( chars[i] !~ chrRegex ) {
            print "Invalid char found:" chars[i]
         }
      }
   }

   BEGIN {
      FIELDWIDTHS="4 4 26"
      chrRegex = "[[:alpha:][:space:],/-]"
      fldRegex = "^(" chrRegex "){26}$"
   }

   {
      if ( $3 ~ fldRegex ) {
         print "Line " NR ": OK"
      }
      else {
         print "Line " NR ": Problem in field"
         print "$3:"$3
         showchar($3)
      }
   }
' "$filename"
```

Your `showchar()` function could just be this though:

```
print "Invalid char(s) found:", gensub(chrRegex,"","g",$3)
```

e.g.

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

filename="$1"

awk '
   BEGIN {
      FIELDWIDTHS="4 4 26"
      chrRegex = "[[:alpha:][:space:],/-]"
      strRegex = "^" chrRegex "{26}$"
   }

   {
      if ( $3 !~ strRegex ) {
         print "Line " NR ": Problem in field"
         print "$3:"$3
         print "Invalid char(s) found:", gensub(chrRegex,"","g",$3)
      } else {
         print "Line " NR ": OK"
      }
   }
' "$filename"
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
Line 1: Problem in field
$3:JOHN,DOE/-SMITH $*
Invalid char(s) found: $*
Line 2: OK
```

Don't write negative conditions if you can avoid it by the way. You had:

```
if ( !whatever ) {
    do_foo
}
else {
    do_bar
}
```

so ask yourself - under what condition do I call `do_bar`? It's "If it is NOT true that NOT whatever is true" - an inscrutable double negative. Just avoid using `!`s or other negative logic to keep your code clear and simple:

```
if ( whatever ) {
    do_bar
}
else {
    do_foo
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ed, this was very helpful and it solved my problem.
A last detail has arisen though, it seems that my document has some (whitespaces) or (non-whitespaces) that are being detected as invalid chrars, and I thought the [:space:] classs would solve this, but it's not, and using \s and \S is not working either, would you happen to know how we could consider this in chrRegex ?

Comment: It all depends what those spaces are but you could try adding the `[:cntrl:]` character class into the bracket expression. See [the gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Bracket-Expressions) for other character classes that might apply.

Comment: Thanks, I did try with space, blank and cntrl, but none is working. When I copy the supposed invalid character, it looks like a whitespace in the text editor.
How could i escape the printing of variable -> chars[i] to see what it truly is?
print "Invalid char found:" chars[i]

Comment: By the way, the unprintable chars seem to be occupying 2 spaces.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I had a few issues while passing parameters into my function, which was the root cause of the failure, but now my script is running smoothly ;)